# Convergence rule for infinite product $\prod (1+a_n)$ with $a_n$ complex.

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, infinite-product

It is well known that the infinite product $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges if the sum $\sum a_n$ converges, for $a_n>0$.

The proof uses $\exp(x)\leq 1+x$ for $x>0$.

$$ \prod \left( 1+a_n \right) \leq \prod \left( e^{a_n} \right) = e^{\sum a_n} $$

If the sum converges, so does the product, because the RHS $\geq$ LHS.

**Question:** If we consider $a_n$ to be **complex**, does the following inequality prove a similar rule: $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges if the sum $\sum |a_n|$ converges?

$$ \left| \prod \left( 1+a_n \right) \right | \leq \prod \left( 1+|a_n| \right) \leq \prod \left( e^{|a_n|} \right) = e^{\sum |a_n|} $$

Is this is a sufficient and correct proof?

**Note:** Some sources add a condition that $a_n\neq-1$, but I don't see why because the sum would diverge anyway. What am i missing?

**Edit:** added abs bars as per comments below.

Comment: You're missing abs. Bars on the LHS of the last equation.

Comment: $\prod(1+a_n)$  is a complex number, so you can’t say it is $\leq$ anything.

Comment: Also, $\exp(x)\color{red}{\geq} 1+x$ and this is true for all $x,$ not just $x>0.$

Comment: If $a_n=-1$ for some $n$ then the convergence of the product is trivial since it is zero, this is the reason why this condition is added I think

Comment: You’d then need to show why $$\left|\prod(1+a_n)\right|$$being bounded implies the product converges. For example, if $a_n=e^{i/n}-1,$ the product is bounded, but the product doesn’t converge. This case doesn’t fit your case, because $\sum|a_n|$ doesn’t converge, but it is bounded.

Comment: @K.defaoite thanks for the correction, I've added the bars to the LHS. Is the logic now correct?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you're right the inequality is true for all $x$. I wonder why so many textbooks still add the condition $x>0$>

Comment: @ThomasAndrews your example with $a_n=e^{i/n}-1$ doesn't seem to pose a problem because the sum $\sum a_n$ diverges. What am i missing?

Comment: My point was that $|\prod (1+a_n)|$ being bounded is not enough to show the product converges. I already said it doesn’t satisfy the initial condition. @tariq The point is, knowing that the product is bounded is not enough to know it converges. (The theorem is true, but the proof is wrong, so I couldn’t very well come up with a completely contradictory example.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - thanks for explaining the proof is wrong. Any pointers to easy-to-read proofs?

Answer (score 2):

$A_n:= \prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k)$ 
$B_n:= \prod_{k=1}^n (1+|a_k|)$
So $|A_n| \le |B_n|$. Now, for all $n<m$:
$$
\begin{align}
|A_n-A_m|&=|A_n|\left| \prod_{k=n+1}^m (1+a_k)-1\right|
\\
&=|A_n| \left| \sum_{i=1}^{m-n} \sum_{E \subset \{n+1,\dots,m\} : \#E=i} \prod_{j \in E} a_j \right| (*) 
\\
&\le |A_n|\left| \sum_{i=1}^{m-n} \sum_{E \subset \{n+1,\dots,m\} : \#E=i} \prod_{j \in E} |a_j|\right| 
\\
&=|A_n|\left| \prod_{k=n+1}^m (1+|a_k|)-1\right|
\\
&\le |B_n| \left| \prod_{k=n+1}^m (1+|a_k|)-1\right|
\\
&=|B_m-B_n|
\end{align}$$
where the "mysterious sum" in (*) is just a formal way to write the expansion $$( 1+b_1)(1+b_2)...(1+b_l)- 1=(b_1+\dots)+(b_1b_2+\dots)+\dots$$
So $|A_n-A_m| \le |B_n-B_m|$. Besides $B_n$ converges, hence the conclusion.

Comment: +1 Nice. You have a lot of extra absolute values. $|A_n|\leq B_n.$ No absolute value needed on the right hand side. Similarly when you replace the $a_j$ with $|a_j|,$ the outer absolute values can go away. Getting $|A_n-A_m|\leq B_n-B_m.$