# Easy proof that if $\sum |a_n|$ converges then so does $\prod (1+a_n)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

I can't seem to find an easy proof that:

- If $\sum |a_n|$ converges then so does $\prod (1+a_n)$

where $a_n$ is complex, and the sum and product are infinite.

---

I have know there is a simple explanation that says the product is bounded if the sum converges (or is bounded) but this is not as strong a statement as required.

I have asked a related question but the comments led me to this better question.
[Convergence rule for infinite product $\prod (1+a_n)$ with $a_n$ complex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191327/convergence-rule-for-infinite-product-prod-1a-n-with-a-n-complex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we'd like to take logarithms to relate a sum and a product. So, assume first that none of the $a_n$ lie on the ray $(-\infty, -1],$ so that we may define a branch of the logarithm function $\log(1+z)$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, -1]$ which we can use on the $a_n.$ Since $|a_n|\rightarrow 0$ by the series convergence, only finitely many of the terms will lie on $(-\infty, -1],$ and so this is in fact sufficient to see the general case, since we can remove those finitely many bad terms from our product without influencing the convergence.

If $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges, then so does $\sum_n \log(1+a_n).$ This is really the crucial claim; noticing that the exponentionals of the partial sums gives the partial product easily shows that the convergence of this sum is equivalent to convergence of the product.

This fortunately follows easily from the limit comparison test. Note that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log(1+a_n)}{a_n} = 1,$$
since $a_n\rightarrow 0$ and so we actually have a difference quotient
$$\frac{\log(1+a_n)}{a_n} = \frac{\log(1+a_n) - \log 1}{a_n - 0}$$
of the $f(z) = \log(1+z)$ function at $z=0.$ The derivative there is $f'(0) = 1,$ and so this limit follows.

Comment: thanks. One step I don't understand is: If $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges, then so does $\sum_n \log(1+a_n)$. I guess this is obvious to many, but I can't see it. Would appreciate help.

Comment: That follows from the limit comparison test, as I outlined in the answer.

Comment: Is the following a correct understanding of your answer? (1) the limit comparison test shows that if $\sum a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum \log(1+a_n)$, (2) convergence of $\sum \log(1+a_n)$ is equivalent to convergence of $\log \prod (1+a_n)$ and so also $\prod (1+a_n)$, because if $X$ converges so does $\log (X)$. I think I have missed the connection to $|a_n|$ as this argument is only about $a_n$.

Comment: Sleeping on it seems to have helped, $|a_n| \geq a_n$ so if the series converges absolutely it also converges conditionally. Is that right?

Comment: @Tariq Yes, every absolutely convergent series converges conditionally.